Why doesn't my 'Members' table exist despite applying migrations?
In Entity Framework Core with SQLite in a .NET console application where despite applying migrations the 'Members' table does not seem to exist in the SQLite database I configured a connection string ("DefaultConnectionString": "DataSource=members.db;") in appsettings.json and defined a Member class for the Members table. My MemberContext class extends DbContext with a DbSet<Member>.
After applying migrations (.NET Entity Framework migrations add and database update) indicating successful schema creation, I attempted to query the Members table in Program.cs. However, I encountered a Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException stating:

no such table: Members

Program.cs:
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Uebung;
using Uebung.Data.Models;


await using var db = new MemberContext();

Console.WriteLine($"Database path: {db.MemberDb}");

Console.WriteLine("Querying all members:");

var results =
    from member in db.Members
    select member;

await foreach (var s in results.AsAsyncEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Member: " + s.Vorname + " " + s.Nachname);
}

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings":
  {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "DataSource=members.db;"
  }
}

Member.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Uebung.Data.Models;

public class MemberContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }

    public string MemberDb { get; set; }

    public MemberContext()
    {
        MemberDb = "members.db";
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={MemberDb}");
    }
}


public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Vorname { get; set; }
    public string? Nachname { get; set; }
}

AppDbContext.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Uebung;

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Uebung.Data.Models.Member> Members { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}


Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database? SQLite is file based and Data Source=members.db connects to a file in the application's working folder. During debugging, that's bin\debug. Anything in bin\debug gets replaced when you rebuild your application

I'm not sure how "DataSource=members.db;" relates to the bin\debug folder. Can you clarify how I should adjust the connection string

Use sqlite-net-pcl, it has a method called SQLiteAsyncConnection.CreateTableAsync(), which allows you to create SQlite database files asynchronously in your runtime directory.
For EF Core, use context.Database.EnsureCreated() in your application could create the database if not already created.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created#ensurecreated
